# Symbian C++ STOMP library

Tags: c++, symbian, s60

I want my S60 Application to utilize the Stomp protocol.

Although it would be fairly simple to implement myself (but nothing is ever as simple as I hope with Symbian) - I am wondering if anyone has any experience in this already.

It seems a Stomp library exists in almost every other language already. The closest match for Symbian would be the C++ library listed [here](http://stomp.codehaus.org/Clients) but that is embedded quite integrally within the ActiveMQ source.

Can anyone offer any advice/experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this is still relevant - I've just finished my implementation of a STOMP client for Symbian, fully using the Active Scheduler framework. We're going to release it as opensource once I get something set up on Google Code.

As Adam says - the implementation needed to be purely within the Symbian framework or it would be unusable (i.e. you'd either need to thread it - arg - or it would just cause all sorts of blocking problems).

I'd also like to get in touch with the STOMP people and have it listed on the website, but haven't been able to find a contact - does anyone here know the best way to do it?

Comment: Hi, you can get a hold of the STOMP folks in the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/stomp-spec)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Stomp messaging for non-Java programmers](http://www.martynov.org/2009/03/stomp-messaging-for-non-java.html) is of any help.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know the STOMP protocol inside out; it's just the implementation of it in Symbian C++ that is the daunting task.

I will have to try it myself and I will share my results.